# jQuery ui failing to load 1 in 10 times (approx)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, sharepoint, requirejs

We're am building a SharePoint 2013 site (not sure if SharePoint is affecting it or not) with which I am using jQuery, jQuery-ui, requireJS and angular.

We've got require and angular to play nicely together, loading in the required js files/controllers as and when they are needed.

However, we are having issues with jQuery-ui.. Ever so often (1 in 10 approximately), it fails to load properly. The page has fully loaded, and the jquery and jquery UI files are listed under sources, yet no UI functions work.

For example, my calendar controls error when loading, with "*undefined is not a function*".
I can type "  **$('#datepicker').datepicker**" in the console window, and I get "*undefined*" back. When jQuery UI does successfully load, I get the expected result in the console window..

I have tried loading the jQuery and jQuery UI files directly at the top of the page, and not via require, but this fails to work to resolve the issue..

Can anyone suggest what may be going wrong here please?

Thanks
Danny

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: But, just reproduced in Firefox too..

Comment: There was a known bug with chrome and SP2010, when javascript sometimes didn't load properly. There is a big chance, that the same issue is still present in SP2013. Checkout this blog post http://withinsharepoint.com/archives/256

Comment: I tried implementing that code, but doesn't seem to have any affect.. I added in some console.logs to see if it even executes the code, and it doesn't

Comment: There is one more idea that comes to my mind - that somehow, jQuery loads after angular and jqueryui, and overwrites both of these. I would log the time of loading these files.

Comment: I'll try the logging load time tip.. but where should I add this? inside the actual js files themselves? (currently minified versions). Regarding first suggested fix, I had it in the incorrect place, and I now get "_spBodyOnloadCalled" is not defined when it tries to execute it..

Comment: ahh, lower case "l".. _spBodyOnLoadWrapper

Comment: I would say, that somewhere in RequireJS - cause i think you're using this to load all other files?

Comment: Issue fixed: I was loading jquery a second time in require, which was causing the issues.
I've taken jquery out of require now, and loading directly on page, as pretty much every page in the site uses it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed: I was loading jQuery a second time in require, which was causing the issues. I've taken jQuery out of require now, and loading directly on page, as pretty much every page in the site uses it anyway. –